# How to grant access to azure resource group to an external user programmatically

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

i have a doubt regarding adding users to Azure resource group. 
If i need to add a internal user to the Azure AD, i can execute New-AzureADUser
and then New-AzureRmRoleAssignment to grant permissions to the resource group. 
what if it is for external users? 
In which case, we need to use New-AzureADMSInvitation which sends an invitation to the external user and i ve verified from the azure portal that user is indeed getting added to Azure AD. 
But how do i grant permissions to this user to the RG since New-AzureRmRoleAssignment doesn't seem to work for non-organization accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command works fine on my side.

After executing `New-AzureADMSInvitation`, then accept to join the AAD, navigate to the email address which you invited -> Get Started.

Then you could find the user in your AAD users.

[image]

**Test command**:

```
New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -ObjectId "<ObjectId>" -RoleDefinitionName "Owner" -Scope "<ResourceGroupId>"
```

[image]

Comment: hi Joy, it worked after using the object Id instead of -signinname. Although the new-azurermroleassignment throws this error:  New-AzureRmRoleAssignment : Exception of type 'Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException' was thrown.  But i ve verified that the user is indeed getting added to the RG.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me by creating an AAD Group with the role you want and then adding the external users into the group. You can add users to the group using `Add-AzureADGroupMember`. FYI this also worked independently of the user accepting the invite.